# python fabric cd context manager does not work from Linux to Windows

Tags: python, linux, fabric

I have a fabric task using which I need to run some commands on a remote Windows machine. In this task, I need to change the current working directory on the remote machine and I'm using `cd` context manager to do this. This works fine when run the fabric script from a Windows machine, but I get the following error when I run from a Linux/Mac machine:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
Fatal error: run() received nonzero return code 1 while executing!
```

Here's my fabric script:

```
from fabric.api import run, env, cd

env.user = 'abc'
env.password = 'xyz'
env.shell = 'cmd.exe /c'

def task1():
    with cd('C:\\temp\\test'):
        run('dir')
```

What am I missing here and how can I make it work from Linux?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at `Fabric's` source code, here is the implementation of `cd`:

```
def cd(path):
    return _change_cwd('cwd', path)

def _change_cwd(which, path):
    path = path.replace(' ', '\ ')
    if state.env.get(which) and not path.startswith('/') and not path.startswith('~'):
       new_cwd = state.env.get(which) + '/' + path
    else:
        new_cwd = path
    return _setenv({which: new_cwd})
```

=> The new working directory has a mix of '\' and '/' characters, which Windows may misinterpret. If I'm not mistaken, and your Windows server version is recent enough, then it should accept the '/' slashes, so try to change your context instruction to `cd('C:/temp/test')`

If it doesn't work, then what is your Windows server's current directory ? You can figure it out by printing `env.cwd`. Maybe it is on another drive, but I doubt that...

Answer (score 1):

Just as a hint, wouldn't this work?

```
from fabric.api import run, env, cd

env.user = 'abc'
env.password = 'xyz'
env.shell = 'cmd.exe /c'

def task1():
    # with cd('C:\\temp\\test'):
    run('cd C:\\temp\\test')
    run('dir')
```

In order to do an on-the-go fix on the `_change_cwd` method, this command

```
import os
print(os.sep)

# '/' in unix like
# '\' in windows like
```

can help to have a system wise directory separator.

Comment: They explicitly say that does not work. Each command has its own shell session: https://www.fabfile.org/faq.html?highlight=cd#my-cd-workon-export-etc-calls-don-t-seem-to-work